# I got a circuit solution but can't understand why I made a mistake

Tags: operational-amplifier

[image]

I was trying to solve [this](http://www.ilectureonline.com/lectures/subject/ENGINEERING/28/255/3577) exercise on my own and I did as follows:

1. Call i1 the current out of the first op-amp
2. Call 12 the current out of the second op-amp
3. Applied KCL at the ground node so i1 + i2 = 0, since no current is going through the voltage generator
4. Applied Ohm law to Vout so Vout = i2 (R2 + Rf2)
5. Solving for i2 the eq at point 3 --> i2 = -i1
6. Applying Ohm law on R1: i1 = Vs / R1 (since in the ideal op-amp the inverting and non-inverting terminals sit at the same voltage
7. Putting toghether 4,5,6 Vout = (-Vs)(R2 + Rf2)/R1

This result is clearly wrong but I can't find the mistake in the procedure, does anyone spot it?

Comment: Perhaps somebody in the forum can help you - but without any circuit diagram it would be a waste of time.

Comment: The circuit diagram is in the link

Comment: Please embed the schematic into your question and note that the one on the link is incorrect and pointless.

Comment: The schematics is in this link, it's a thumbnail you have to click it. Anyway I'll add the thumb. Please read before downvoting, there's everything https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=est9UUt0G5g

Comment: Why do you use KVL for the opamp output currents?  I1 + I2 = 0A What?  where is the summing node? The opamp output act just like independent voltage-controlled voltage sources. Also, add the schematic into your question.

Comment: @G36 I derived i1 + i2 = 0 by applying KCL at the ground node

Comment: Why are you still posting links to stuff that is either wrong or irrelevant? This Q and A site only needs a picture of the schematic. You say `This result is clearly wrong` but you don't say what you are trying to solve. You need to be much clearer and less ambiguous.

Comment: @UmbertoFontanazza You cannot do that, you need to treat them as independent currents. To be able to see it draw a voltage source between GND and output. As shown here https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Q3RMFpGGcZM

Comment: Problem 1: "*i1 + i2 = 0*". You've forgotten that the current from the op-amp outputs has to come from somewhere and that's the op-amp power supply. Draw in the return path for that current if you want to approach the problem that way.

Comment: My recommenation: When a circuit consists of two identical decoupled gain stages it is - to me - quite logical to consider (as a first step) one stage only.

Comment: Please change the title of your question to something more meaningful. Remember that we are doing this for future readers as well.